# Using local variable from a for loop as name for dictionary key overwrites previous key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, naming-conventions

When I try to add a value using `i+1` to my dictionary as the name in my for loop it replaces the previous key even though they technically have separate name. What I am currently trying to do is make an encryption system, and in order to do so I have it randomly generate a keyword then make that keyword into a list separating each individual character. That works fine, anyways I am using dictionaries in order to try to make soft-coded variables to an extent. I want a variable for every character so that they can be referenced later, rather than having a lot of variables just overwritten from zero. Let me show you the code I have so far.

```
import urllib.request
import random

word_url = "http://svnweb.freebsd.org/csrg/share/dict/words?view=co&content-type=text/plain"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(word_url)
long_txt = response.read().decode()
words = long_txt.splitlines()
keyword = random.choice(words)

def split(word):
    return list(word)
def getLetters(word):
    localvar1 = list(word)
    localvar2 = len(localvar1)
    for i in range(localvar2):
        global letters
        letters = {}
        letters[i+1] = localvar1[i].copy()
        print(letters)
def printLetters():
    for i in range(len(letters)):
        try:
            print(letters[1+i])
        except:
            ValueError
```

That's all of the code the code specifically that makes the dictionary is here.

```
def getLetters(word):
    localvar1 = list(word)
    localvar2 = len(localvar1)
    for i in range(localvar2):
        global letters
        letters = {}
        letters[i+1] = localvar1[i].copy()
        print(letters)
```

I think the problem is that it recognizes `i+1` as a singular name even though every time the for loop, loops i increases in value. I've tried everything I can think of and this is my last resort. I've practically looked at every online article I could fine, though I might've missed something. I've tried using `__setitem__` creating new lists from that list and a bunch of other stuff I can't remember. I've worked on this for hours and now I just have a headache, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So what is your expected result of `getLetters`? It also errors out due to the `.copy()` as strings do not have a copy method.

Comment: don't create dictionary `letters = {}` inside `for`-loop because you destroy previous content in every loop and you have only last value. Create `letters = {} ` before `for`-loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its overwriting the variable because you’re redefining it within your loop as a blank dictionary then only putting one value inside it. Move those 2 lines outside the loop and it’s fixed. Also you don’t need to use those local variables, just use enumerate.

```
def getLetters(word):
    global letters
    letters = {}
    for i, letter in enumerate(word, 1):
        letters[i] = letter
    print(letters)
```

This prints:

```
{1: 'W', 2: 'h', 3: 'i', 4: 't', 5: 'c', 6: 'o', 7: 'm', 8: 'b'}
```

**Note** I don’t exactly condone this because it’s very unconventional to do this. Why not just return the dictionary and when calling it assign the result to a variable then now it’s a global value in this context. Also a simple dict comprehension will do exactly what you’re trying to do as well:

```
def getLetters(word):
    return {i:l for i, l in enumerate(word, 1)}

letters = getLetters(keyword)
```

**Edit** or as @furas so smartly mentioned, just use:

```
return dict(enumerate(word, 1))
```

All this said I don’t believe you even really need this function. To get the second letter in this dict you’d use `letters[2]` whereas if it were just left as a string value it can be treated similarly to a list so `keyword[1]` would be the same result, or just use `keyword[i+1]` if you must have the first index start from 1.

Comment: or even `return dict(enumerate(word, 1))`

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you, I just now realized you were right, I was resetting the dictionary every time. Thank you for taking the time out of your day, to help me through my confusion.

Comment: No problem if this answers your question please mark it as so using the check mark to the left of the answer it’s very appreciated!